# How to create a VM jenkins with url to access remotely from outside

Tags: jenkins, azure-active-directory, jenkins-plugins, azure-storage, virtual

I am having Jenkins in my virtual machine Azure .i need to access it with URL remotely from outside.

Comment: This would require update of the security rule to allow inbound connection from outside to the VM. Additionally if you are looking for URL then A record will also be needed

Comment: Any more questions? Or if the answer is helpful you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

No matter which the steps you have done, create the VM with a cloud-init file to install the Jenkins, or create the VM and then install the Jenkins. There is no difference.

You need to open port 8080 for Jenkins traffic and port 1337 for the Node.js app. If you finish all the settings of Jenkins, then you can browse the Jenkins with the VM public IP and the port 8080 outside the VM, the URL like this: `http://vmPublicIps:8080`. Get all the steps from [Create a VM in Azure with Jenkins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-jenkins-github-docker-cicd).

Or you can just create a Jenkins Server with the image that Azure provided, see [Create a Jenkins server on an Azure Linux VM from the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/jenkins/install-jenkins-solution-template).